# Change the style of an element in an array

Tags: javascript

how can I change the style of an element in an array? I've hidden the class "testimonial" in CSS before, now I want to display a single element of that class. I'm searching for something like this:

```js
let test= document.getElementsByClassName("test");

test[0].style.visibility = "block";
```

Comment: I think you want `display`, not `visibility`. The possible values of `visibility` are `visible` and `invisible`

Comment: @barmar Or want to set `visibility:visible`.

Comment: @Barmar `invisible` or `hidden`?

Comment: Right, `hidden`. I don't use the `visibility` style much.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, only should use the correct css property (it's maybe the `display:block`, in javascript `HTMLElementNodeList[<indexOfElement>].style.display="block"`)